# jQuery validate() for radio buttons with same name, different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

If I have this HTML:

```
<div class="form-group radioInput">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input checked="checked" name="AcknowledgeLSA" type="radio" value="False"> No
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <inputname="AcknowledgeLSA" type="radio" value="True"> Yes
  </label>
</div>
```

And this psuedo-JS (which obviously doesn't work):

```
myForm.validate({
    rules: {
        AcknowledgeLSA:checked : {required: value="True"}
    }
});
```

... how can I have the validation based on the value of the Radio Button being "True"?

I'm needing to change the JS not the HTML. The form is valid if the radio button with the `True` value is selected. The form is not valid is the other `False` radio button is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to use `depends` here:

```
myForm.validate({
    rules: {
        AcknowledgeLSA: {
            required: true,
            depends: function() { 
                         var rbtn = $("input[name='AcknowledgeLSA']:checked");
                         return typeof rbtn !== 'undefined' && rbtn.val() == "True";
                }
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: You can create a custom rule like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("hasValue", function(value, element, param) {
    return value == param;
}, 'Invalid!');

myForm.validate({
    rules: {
        AcknowledgeLSA: {
            hasValue: 'True'
       }
};
```

Comment: yeah I tried that, despite thinking that depends means "when to require that `require: true`" and got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element AcknowledgeLSA, check the 'depends' method.`

Comment: forgot you can't check value of radio button like that. updated the answer. see if it works now.

Comment: I think this is doing what it says it will do (making the field required when it meets the depend condition) but the problem here is that it will always meet the required condition if it has the value of True. I wonder if there is an alternative to `required` like `valueMustBe` so you check what the actual value is and use that check as the source for validation?

Comment: you can create a custom rule for it. update the answer again!

Answer (score 0):

```
myForm.validate({
rules: 
    AcknowledgeLSA : {
        required: true,
        depends: function() { return $('[name="AcknowledgeLSA"]').is(':checked').val() === "True";}
    }
}
});
```

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules

Comment: Im talking about the value attribute of the DOM node being set to the string `"True"`, not the radio button just being required.